# App não passa pelo login

Tags: mobile, ionic2, cross-platform

Estou tentando validar o *login*, mas está passando direto e entrando na *home*, não sei o que pode estar acontecendo:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {LoginPage} from '../login/login';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({ 
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      window.localStorage.removeItem('currentuser');
   if(this.isLoggedin()){
       console.log('you are not logged in');
       this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
   }
  }
    isLoggedin(){
        if(window.localStorage.getItem('currentuser')){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E se você colocar  `if(window.localStorage.getItem('currentuser')){
            return true;
        } else { return false;}`

Comment: O resultado é o mesmo

Comment: Sua lógica é: Se houver item no local.storage, retorne true. Senão, retorne false. Certo?! No momento tem alguma coisa no currentuser gravado?

Comment: Você está usando ionic 1 ou 2?

Comment: Ionic 2. Com o ponto de exclamação, deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Removi a tag ionic e deixei somente ionic 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na sua lógica. A princípio você precisa verificar se está diferente de "logado". Por exemplo:  `!this.isLoggedin()`. Veja abaixo:

```
if(!this.isLoggedin()){
   console.log('you are not logged in');
   this.navCtrl.push(Login);
}
```

Sendo assim, seu método `isLoggedin()` pode ser verificado se existe ou não um item salvo no seu `localStorege` com o valor correspondente. Caso exista, retorne `true`, senão retorne `false`. Veja:

```
isLoggedin(){ 
   return window.localStorage.getItem('currentuser'); 
}
```